# Hidden folders and path too long

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, batch, cmd.exe, path

I have a folder (`C:\Users\Default\myFolder`) that seems empty from the explorer (`C:\Users\Default\myFolder\$nothing`),

but who have sub folders that I can access if I type their path directly (`C:\Users\Default\myFolder\mySubfolder1` ; `C:\Users\Default\myFolder\mySubfolder2` ; ...),

how can I make them visible again? (it's not hidden folders, I truly can't see them).

I tried to copy it (`C:\Users\Default\myFolder`),

but apparently the path is too long for that (Windows shows an error and does not copy them,

even if I copy upper in the folder hierarchy).

But I still can move the folder (`C:\Users\Default\myFolder`).

I can't move/copy the sub folders/files/contents (`C:\Users\Default\myFolder\mySubfolder1` ; `C:\Users\Default\myFolder\mySubfolder2` ; ...) considering that I don't know the name of them

Comment: They are probably hidden.

Comment: They are probably protected system folders, which is a different setting that you can disable by unchecking "hide protected system files and folders"

Comment: @Toto `(it's not hidden folders, I truly can't see them).`

Comment: @LPChip I dunno why. But the folder that I personally created (right click, new folder) is effectively hidden as a system folder. I can see it now. Thanks! (and the too long path problem does not show up when moving. So I can reduce the path before trying to copy)

Comment: The default profile folder is a special one. When creating a new folder, it inherits the attributes of its parent. That's why your folder becomes system from the start.

Comment: When that inheritance chain stops? Because apparently it doesn't happen at any location. So what location can be troublesome?

Comment: Normally it doesn't happen, but it depends on which folder is owner, and that can set a folder as system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The folder is a system folder.

In Windows, there are 2 settings that can hide folders. The show hidden items setting, and the hide protected filesystem items setting. The latter hides files and folders with the system attribute too.

In your example, the folder Default is special, which is why this happens.

Comment: The "Default" folder was an example one. In my situation, the path is completely different (it only shares C:\ with the example). But I get the root reason, thanks!